# pandas equal all column names of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which I have multiple leg columns names like `leg/1 leg/2 leg/3` till leg/24 but the problem is that each leg has multiple string attached with like `leg/1/a1 leg/1/a2`.

For example I have a dataframe like this

```
leg/1/a1 leg/1/a2  leg/2/a1   leg/3/a2
```

I need that all leg names in the dataframe should have equal columns like **leg/1**

For example my required pandas dataframe column names should be

```
leg/1/a1 leg/1/a2  leg/2/a1  leg/2/a2   leg/3/a1   leg/3/a2
```

this should be the output of the dataframe.

for that purpose I have first collected the leg/1 details inside the list

```
legs=['leg/1/a1','leg/1/a2']
```

this list i have created to match all the dataframe column names

After that I have collected all the dataframe column names that are started with leg

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'leg' in col]
```

but the problem is that I am unable to match , any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How come input  has 4 columns but output has 6? do you want to add dummy columns with no values?

Comment: yes this is how i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
column_list = ['leg/1/a1','leg/1/a2','leg/2/a1','leg/3/a2'] #replace with df.columns
col_end_list = set([e.split('/')[-1] for e in column_list]) # get all a1,a2,....an
#Loop theough leg/1/a1 to leg/24/an
for i in range(1,25):
    for c in col_end_list:
        check_str = 'leg/'+str(i)+'/'+c
        if check_str not in column_list: #Check if column doesn't exist ad a column
            df[check_str] = 0 #adding new column
```

Code to preproduce on blank df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([],columns=['leg/1/a1','leg/1/a2','leg/2/a1','leg/3/a2'])
column_list = df.columns
col_end_list = set([e.split('/')[-1] for e in column_list]) # get all a1,a2,....an
#Loop theough leg/1/a1 to leg/24/an
for i in range(1,25):
    for c in col_end_list:
        check_str = 'leg/'+str(i)+'/'+c
        if check_str not in column_list: #Check if column doesn't exist ad a column
            df[check_str] = 0 #adding new column
>>> df.columns
>>> Index(['leg/1/a1', 'leg/1/a2', 'leg/2/a1', 'leg/3/a2', 'leg/2/a2', 'leg/3/a1',
   'leg/4/a1', 'leg/4/a2', 'leg/5/a1', 'leg/5/a2', 'leg/6/a1', 'leg/6/a2',
   'leg/7/a1', 'leg/7/a2', 'leg/8/a1', 'leg/8/a2', 'leg/9/a1', 'leg/9/a2',
   'leg/10/a1', 'leg/10/a2', 'leg/11/a1', 'leg/11/a2', 'leg/12/a1',
   'leg/12/a2', 'leg/13/a1', 'leg/13/a2', 'leg/14/a1', 'leg/14/a2',
   'leg/15/a1', 'leg/15/a2', 'leg/16/a1', 'leg/16/a2', 'leg/17/a1',
   'leg/17/a2', 'leg/18/a1', 'leg/18/a2', 'leg/19/a1', 'leg/19/a2',
   'leg/20/a1', 'leg/20/a2', 'leg/21/a1', 'leg/21/a2', 'leg/22/a1',
   'leg/22/a2', 'leg/23/a1', 'leg/23/a2', 'leg/24/a1', 'leg/24/a2'],
  dtype='object')
```

Comment: it gives all the leg/1/ but it doesnot equalize all columns of different legs like of leg 1

Comment: I have mentioned the required output in the question

Comment: it is equalizing all the dataframe column venky but it is not appending
the if statement inside the loop is not working i guess

this one 
 if check_str not in df.columns: #Check if column doesn't exist ad a column
            print(check_str)

Comment: It does work for me i have added code below to reproduce, you can try that one